# I am getting Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at Fib.run(fibThread.java:52)

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class fibThread {
@SuppressWarnings("resource")

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner fib = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the Length of the Fibonacci Series :");

    int num = fib.nextInt();

    Runnable r = new Fib("Result", num);
    new Thread(r).start();

    try{
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }

    catch (InterruptedException e) {
         System.out.println("Thread interrupted.");
     }

    int[] result =((Fib) r).getResult();
    System.out.print("The Fibonacci Series is :" + result);

}
}
class Fib implements Runnable{
private int num;
int f0=0, f1=1,fn=0;

int arr[] = new int[num];

public Fib(String string, int num) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.num = num;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++){
        fn = f0 + f1;
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = fn;
        arr[i] = fn;
    }
}

public int[] getResult(){

    return arr;
}
}
```

i was given with a Question and I wrote the above code

write a multithreaded program that generates the fibonacci sequence . This program should work as follows:
On the command line, the user will enter the number of fibonacci numbersthat the program is to generate. The program will then create a seperate thread that will generate the fibonacci numbers, placing the sequence in data that can be shared by the threads(an array is probably the most convenient data structure). When the thread finishes execution, the parent thread will output the sequence generated by the child thread.

please help me to solve it....

Comment: Inspiration: http://crunchify.com/write-java-program-to-print-fibonacci-series-upto-n-number/

Comment: You declare `r` to be of type `Runnable`, you assign a `Fib` reference to it, and then you later cast it to be of type `Fib` so that you can call the `getResult()` method.  Why not simply declare `r` to be of type `Fib`?  Then there would be no need for the cast expression.  Sometimes, there's no way to solve a problem without a cast expression, but more often, a cast is a sign of a bad design.

Comment: Your variable names, f0, and f1, are misleading:  They are _initialized_ to fib(0) and fib(1), but after the first iteration of the loop, that's no longer what they equal.  I thought, "what would I name those variables,..." and then realized I would not even use them.  I would write `arr[i] = arr[i-1]+arr[i-2]`.  Of course, in order for that to work, I would have to start my loop with `i=2`, and arr[0] and arr[1] would have to be initialized before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

#### The Reason

You get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `num` is initialized to `0` when `arr` is declared.

```
int num; // <-- 0
int arr[] = new int[num]; // <-- int[0]
public Fib(String string, int num) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.num = num;
}
```

#### To Fix It

You could move the array declaraction into your constructor like

```
int num;
int arr[];
public Fib(String string, int num) {
    this.num = num;
    this.arr = new int[num];
}
```

#### Your Assignment

You need to share the `arr`. I think you were supposed to use a `static` field, and to synchronize. It's generally easier to generate the Fibonacci sequence with [Binet's formula](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Fibonacci_Number_Program#Using_Binet.27s_formula). Your assignment seems to be creating a multi-threaded [Iterative Memoized version](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Mathematics/Fibonacci_Number_Program#Iterative_Memoized_version).